# How to take out single value out of a path of given location in python?

Tags: python, split

I have a path in a python script as:

```
    D://mycom/hjkl/Recent
```

Now i want to print only Recent in the output.
How will i achieve that in my python script?

Comment: Show some effort before you ask. This is quite a trivial task

Answer (score 3):

The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module (more specifically [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)) is what you're looking for:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "D://mycom/hjkl/Recent"
>>> print os.path.basename(path)
'Recent'
```